# SQL Server 2012 Standard server with 50 instances won't uninstall instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I suspect this is an issue because we hit the 50 instance max limit of SQL Server. At the limit it won't install more instances, naturally. However, it seems it won't UNinstall them either. That's worse.

It hangs at the "Select Features" dialogue when you hit next after selecting the SQL Engine for the instance.

I didn't find a lot of info about this. The most interesting hit was this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/24a1e5f3-25f3-48c8-973a-4c6a18578e42/trying-to-uninstall-1-of-50-sql-server-2008-r2-express-hangs-on-please-wait

It also suggest using `setup.exe` with some parameters to uninstall the instance, but I can't get it to do so without starting the GUI and into the normal uninstall which fails.

Elevation does nothing. Reboot doesn't help. Logs only say "canceled by user", because I have to kill it in the end. Nothing obvious prior to that point. Validations are all green.

The setup says it is SQL Server 2012 SP1 - all instances are at 11.0.2100.

---

I' choosing to to answer/close my own question since Microsoft has [closed the ticket with the status of "Won't fix."](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810765/bug-in-setup-exe-verification-on-server-with-50-instances)

Hopefully they will have fixed this for SQL Server 2014, but I have not and do not plan to test that myself, nor do they provide any additional comment on closing the ticket.

Comment: You're trying to setup a big data-set and save on licensing cost, aren't you? I had the same thought once. How is it going?

Comment: Maybe http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/uninstalling-sql-instance-cluster

Comment: I was wrong! This is actually a licensed server! I corrected the title. Not that it is relevant at all to the issue, I think. (We have tons of Express for small datasets. Works like a charm. If they grow too big they're migrated to licensed servers.)

Comment: @Mihai - Thanks, but this is not a clustered instance. Doesn't seem relevant...

Comment: Ok, Hail Mary but could you go into the registry and delete one of the instance name keys (backing it up first)?  (Location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL)  Then see if the installer will only see 49 instances and perform the uninstall of one of the instances cleanly .. then go back and restore the missing key?

Comment: @KennethFisher Thanks, but didn't work. :(

Comment: @KennethFisher Tried to understand the registry and found 4 relevant locations. 1) Value: "InstalledInstances" - a Multi-String listing the instances. 2) Key named <instancename> 3) Key named MSSQL11.<instancename> 4) String-Value under "Instance Names\SQL". Limited my search to the "Microsoft SQL Server" Key-subhive. Tried removing it bits and pieces and all of it. No luck, same error message from command line "uninstall". And still no answer at Connect... For reference: I tried to remove "instance A" from reg and uninstall "instance B", not the same one.

Answer (score 2):

It will likely be because the setup GUI is trying to enumerate all the instances installed  and failing miserably, running the uninstall from the command line should do it

Running the below command with admin privileges will uninstall the SQL server instance with no setup GUI displayed:

```
Setup.exe /Action=Uninstall /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /Q
```

I assume that you only have the SQL Server feature installed, if you have others you want to remove, you can just add them in a comma separated list of values, such as `/FEATURES=SQL,RS,Tools`

For different instances, just replace MSSQLSERVER with the name of the instance you want to remove.

Command line reference for setup.exe is available here:

[Install SQL Server 2012 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx#Uninstall)

Comment: What error are you getting when running the command?

Comment: I misread the first "note" on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx - It says /QS doesn't work for uninstall, but I read it as /Q too. Still doesn't work for me though: >Setup.exe /Action=Uninstall /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=NAME /Q

The following error occurred:
SQL Server 2012 cannot add any more instances. To continue installing this instance, you must uninstall an existing instance.

Error result: -2146233079
Result facility code: 19
Result error code: 5385

Obviously it validates AS IF it were to install more instanses, so it has deadlocked! How about: sc delete ??

Comment: sc delete won't help you as I would imagine it's looking in the registry for the instance list, deleting the service won't help with that, plus you're likely to make the uninstall fail if you do get past the first error.

Comment: What I figure too. It probably does a whole lot more than just add the service when "installing" the instance, however I guess the only way out now is to hack this registry of instances to be able to run the uninstaller on one instance. Then "hack it back" to normalize the server. Seriously MicroSoft... Is this really an actual bug in SQL Server 2012? Pretty horrible!

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty poor, are you using the latest version of the installer?  Grabbing the latest version of it might just help if it is an installer bug.

Comment: Good idea. Tried updating it, and the box. No Luck.

Comment: Registered as bug on Connect after SQL MVP suggested it. -https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810765/bug-in-setup-exe-verification-on-server-with-50-instances - Will update this post.